# Hide method in .Net Hierarchy

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have 3 classes:

1. BaseClass
2. Middleclass inheriting from BaseClass
3. ClientClass inheriting the Middleclass

I wonder how do I hide a method at BaseClass to not appear in ClientClass?

Example:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public void BaseMethod1()
    {
    }

    public void BaseMethod2()
    {
    }
}

public class MiddleClass : BaseClass
{
    public void MiddleMethod()
    {
        this.BaseMethod1();
    }
}

public class ClientClass : MiddleClass
{
    public void Test()
    {
        this.MiddleMethod();
        this.BaseMethod1(); // I can't see this method here
    }
}
```

Edit: I modified my sample, I put "this.BaseMethod1();" in MiddleClasse

Comment: Could you explain *why* do you want to do this?

Comment: Not appear publicly, or not at all? You could use a modified version of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16236701/866022) to make it private in `ClientClass` while still keeping it public in `MiddleClass`.

Comment: It seems you are using inheritance not in the rigth place

Comment: You're trying to wantonly and brutally violate the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). This is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, which breaks the direct inheritance tree:

```
public interface IBaseClass
{
    void BaseMethod1();
    void BaseMethod2();
}

public class BaseClass : IBaseClass
{
    public void BaseMethod1()
    {
    }

    public void BaseMethod2()
    {
    }
}

public class MiddleClass : IBaseClass
{
    BaseClass @base;

    public MiddleClass() { this.@base=new BaseClass(); }

    public void MiddleMethod()
    {
        @base.BaseMethod1();
    }

    void IBaseClass.BaseMethod1()
    {
        //@base.BaseMethod1();
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void BaseMethod2()
    {
        @base.BaseMethod2();
    }
}

public class ClientClass : MiddleClass
{
    public void Test()
    {
        this.MiddleMethod();
        // 'ClientClass' does not contain a definition for 'BaseMethod1'
        //this.BaseMethod1(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: That's close. Though you should be aware that you can still do `((IBaseClass)this).BaseMethod1()`.

Comment: @svick - Not now, I edited the post to throw an exception in this case. The base method is ONLY accessible through `MiddleMethod()`.

Comment: Points for answering the letter of the question, anyway :-D Not sure this is the kind of code that should necessarily be encouraged, though...

Comment: This is the reason interfaces where invented. To deal with loose inheritance problems like this.

Comment: Well - a possible downside is that `ClientClass` no longer IS-A `BaseClass`. If there were other `BaseClass` members that `ClientClass` was expecting to inherit, it no longer does, unless you use more code to make them available through `MiddleClass`. Also, `IBaseClass.BaseMethod1` now has to be understood to throw `NotImplementedException` under certain (undetectable) circumstances, which makes using this hierarchy in a polymorphic way a bit like a game of Russian Roulette :P

Comment: @shambulator - I agree, so the developer needs to add a disclaimer in the DocXml that not all methods of `IBaseClass` are necessary implemented at all times.

Answer (score 4):

You need to define that method as private. Just for reference, here you have more information about access modifiers

> **public**: The type or member can be accessed by any other code in the same assembly or another assembly that references it.
>
> **private**: The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or struct.
>
> **protected**: The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or struct, or in a class that is derived from that class.
>
> **internal**: The type or member can be accessed by any code in the same assembly, but not from another assembly.

Comment: I think the implicit question here is how to make the method invisible to `ClientClass` while keeping it accessible in `MiddleClass` which, as others have pointed out, probably calls for a re-design.

Comment: Thanks Claudio! I tried change access modifiers, but don't work.

Answer (score 4):

I've always believed that if you want to hide some functionality in a base class from some, but not all, derived classes then it's a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) and your design needs re-thinking.

Comment: that would also violate the Liskov substitution principle

Answer (score 0):

Define method BaseMethod1 as protected in BaseClass,than you can use function BaseMethod1 in MiddleClass.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    protected void BaseMethod1()
    {
    }

    public void BaseMethod2()
    {
    }
}

public class MiddleClass : BaseClass
{
    public void MiddleMethod()
    {
       base.BaseMethod1();
    }
    // hide method
    private new void BaseMethod1()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: But what if he needs the base class functionality in `MiddleClass` using `new` will override the base class implementation.

Comment: @ByteBlast:  If the implementation is `base.BaseMethod()`, then he'll have it in `MiddleClass` but not in `ClientClass`.

Comment: @misak It isn't. Have you tried this code? `ClientClass` defined as per the question can still call the `BaseClass` version of `BaseMethod1`.

Comment: Dont you need the `new` keyword also as in `private new void BaseMethod1() { }`?

Comment: @ja72 That makes no difference. Using `new` just makes the hiding explicit and stops the compiler from warning you.

Comment: I see your point. Well it makes for good coding style though ..?..!